# Backup and restore partitioned tables in PostgreSQL containing check constraints

Tags: postgresql, restore, database-backups, database-partitioning, pg-dump

I have partitioned tables in my database. I want to backup the tables and restore them on the localhost. By using pg_dump, I was able to backup the parent table but the data was not copied in the backup file. When I restore it using psql or pg_restore data, it was not restored. In the case of partition tables, it contains check constraints. What is the solution to backup and restore the partitioned tables with the data?

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? (`select version()` will tell you) How are the tables partitioned? (using the old deprecated inheritance approach, or the "new" declarative approach?) What is the exact `pg_dump` command line you were using? And what version of `pg_dump` are you using (`pg_dump -V` will tell you)

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL 10.4 version.                                                             
 Commands im using are for backup -> pg_dump -h host -U username -d db -W -t table  > /tmp/rp_table_1.sql  For restoring 


psql -h host -U username -W -d db < /tmp/rp_table_1..sql

Comment: pg_dump version pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 12.10 (Ubuntu 12.10-1.pgdg21.04+1)
approach is probably old deprecated where check constraint is used to create the partitions.

Comment: What do you mean "probably"? You have to tell us, otherwise we don't know what to answer.

Comment: we have created customized partition table so i think so its old inheritance approach.          house_balochistan is partition table while house is parent table.                    
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.house_balochistan
(
   
    -- Inherited from table public.house: name_ur character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT house_balochistan_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT roads_balochistan_check CHECK (fn_partition_check(geom, 'Balochistan'::text))
)
    INHERITS (public.house)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;